# search for periods and randomly decide to add a word after the period 50% of the time

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to search through a textarea and find the periods, after finding the periods I need to randomly decide if I should add "arrr" after the period this should be a 50/50 chance of having the word printed in there.
HELP ME Please!!! here's what i have going on so far, it's kind of a mess
    document.getElementById("translate").onclick = function changed()
    {

```
var outpara = document.getElementById("out")
var paragraph = document.getElementById("input").value;
paragraph = paragraph.toLowerCase();
while(paragraph.indexOf("hello")!== -1) 
{ 
paragraph = paragraph.replace("hello", "Ahoy"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("excuse me")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("excuse me", "arrr"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("sir")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("sir", "matey"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("madam")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("madam", "proud beauty"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("officer")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("officer", "foul blaggart"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("where is")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("where is", "whar be"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("can you help me find")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("can you help me find", "know ye"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("is that")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("is that", "be that"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("the")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("the", "th'"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("my")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("my", "me"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("your")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("your", "yer"); 
}   
while(paragraph.indexOf("restroom")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("restroom", "head"); 
}   
while(paragraph.indexOf("restaurant")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("restaurant", "galley"); 
}
while(paragraph.indexOf("hotel")!== -1) 
{
paragraph = paragraph.replace("hotel", "fleabag inn"); 
}
var x = paragraph.split(" ");
var repl= [Math.floor (Math.random()* 2)]
    if(repl === 0 || repl === 1)
        paragraph.replace(".", ". arrrr")
    else
        paragraph.replace(".", ".")
var readySentance=[];
while(x.indexOf(".")!==-1)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < paragraph.length; ++i)
        {
        x.push(". Arrrr");
        }
}
```

and my HTML looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Pirate Translator</title>
<!--<link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />-->
</head>
<body>
<h1> Land Lovin' Lady's Pirate Translator</h1>
<p> Simply click on the buttons to translate words and/or phrases from English to  pirate talk</p><hr />
<form name = "pirateForm">

<div>   
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<textarea id="out" readonly></textarea>
<input onclick= "changed();" type="button" id ="translate" value="translate"/>
<input onclick="clearArea2()" type="button" id="clear2" value= "clear"/>
<script src="pirate4.js"></script><br>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is aside from your question, and I don't know if this is something you're ready for, but when there's code that repeats and repeats, it's generally a missed opportunity to make the computer do the work. The principle from the book _The Pragmatic Programmer_ is "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY).

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression (so that you can specify the `g` global flag) and a callback in the replace:

```
paragraph = paragraph.replace(/\./g, function(){ return Math.random() < 0.5 ? ". arrrr" : "." });
```

As that is replacing all occurances with one command, you won't get stuck in a loop that will put an `arrrr` after every period no matter how many tries it has to do to get through the randomness.

In the same way you can use a regular expression in all your replacements, so that you don't need to have them in a loop. This will replace all occurances of `hello`:

```
paragraph = paragraph.replace(/hello/g, "Ahoy");
```